Why are ._ files being created when uploading files from an ExFAT drive to Google Drive?
I’m encountering an issue when uploading files from an external hard drive formatted as ExFAT. For every file I upload through Google Chrome, a second file with the same name is created, prefixed with ._ and with a size of 4KB.
Here’s the key detail: The ._ files are not visible on the external drive before the upload (I have enabled hidden files visibility to check this).
They only appear after the files are uploaded.
My understanding so far: I know that macOS creates ._ files to store metadata (like resource forks or Finder attributes) on file systems that don’t natively support macOS metadata, such as ExFAT. However, in this case, I am not copying these metadata files manually, and they don’t seem to exist on the drive before the upload process starts.
My question: Why are these ._ files being created during the upload process if they are not visible nor selected beforehand on the drive?
Additional context:

My external drive is formatted as ExFAT for compatibility with both macOS and Windows.
The files being uploaded do not seem to have any special Finder attributes, tags, or custom icons (at least as far as I can tell).
When I upload files to Google Drive using Google Chrome, either by dragging them from a Finder window to the drop area in the browser or by using the "+ New > Folder upload" option in the Google Drive web interface, a second file with the same name is automatically created for each uploaded file. These additional files are prefixed with ._ and have a size of 4KB.

I’d appreciate any insights into why this might happen and practical steps to resolve or prevent it!

"For every file I upload through Google Chrome..." Exactly what is your workflow?

Updated the OP, including "When I upload files to Google Drive using Google Chrome, I drag them from a Finder window to the drop area in the browser."

Google Drive doesn't support extended attributes.  If the file has them, you're going to get dot-files.   Whether or not your source folder has them, or how they're stored, I decline to stipulate.

As a workaround, I have issued the following command over the folder to be copied find .  -name '._*' -delete and then uploaded the files

See wikipedia for the reason. This is the AppleDouble file format.

We strongly prefer one question per question. If this gets closed or goes off the rails with people answering what they think is the question, please post a short and clear picture of what specifically you are doing and what the results you get and ask one question only, please. See [tour] for examples of this process.

Things you might include are a listing of exactly what files look like on the drive, exactly what they look like after chrome uploads a few, what version of chrome and macOS are in use. Also if you copy one or two files to your downloads folder on the Mac and upload from there, is AppleDouble format evident in drive? People will have all sorts of ideas like trying Safari as well…

@bmike, I have edited to questions to be just one question. Please remove your downvote so this question can survive. I am sure this is affecting a lot of users

Very nice edit - thanks! If you want to edit any of the good comments into an answer you post, that explain backstory you can flag your post to ask mods to clean up comments if you wish at any point

Also, votes are anonymous here, so make sure you show some love to the people that posted answers and your question won’t ever go away even if its net -1 as more people come and vote on it after you edited it.

It sounds like you're actually uploading folders, not individual files. If you upload a macOS folder, it could contain invisible files.
My solution would be to create a folder in Google Drive first, and then either drag or upload the files, rather than uploading an existing folder.

Thanks for explaining this, it makes sense. I am selecting this as the best answer as per explaining this weird beahviour, although your suggestion, which is a good idea, can be applied only when there aren't many subfolders as in my case

macOS and many other OS hide files that begin with .
Press shift command . on macOS to toggle the invisibility of these files to check if they’re present even if you don’t see them in finder or file open/select dialogs.
The dot_clean command deletes the '._' dot files that carry some Mac-specific extended file attributes that Windows does not understand (and are usually not needed anyway):

Launch the Terminal app.
Copy and paste the following command to the Terminal window:
dot_clean -mnf

and type a space to the end.
Drag the USB drive to the Terminal so that its path is added to the end of the dot_clean command.
Press Return.
Eject the USB drive without opening it in the Finder (so new dot files are not generated).

A GUI alternative is to use "Blue Harvest" that does the same.
The best solution would if the other OSs just ignored those dotfiles.

The question doesn't ask how to remove them, it asks why they're created and how to prevent it.

Let’s see if we can find a post that asks how to clean these up, this doesn’t seem practical to clean google drive using chrome browser and the OP already said those files aren’t present on the ExFAT drive so you’d need to explain how they’re wrong for this to be an answer here. Your answer would get a good reception to a post asking how to bulk clean things IMO.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
